# ExpressJs Jade rendering issue

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am rendering content but it's not displaying. This is my code:

**layout : views/layouts/main.jade**

```
    .container
        .row
            .col-lg-12
                #{pgtopic}  
        .row
            .col-lg-8.mx-auto
                h2 About this page
                block xcontent      

                ul
                    li list item 1
                    li list item 2
```

**on the page : views/pages/users.jade**

```
extends ../layouts/main

block xcontent
    h1 This is the INDEX PAGE 
    p. 
       this is a multi-line paragraph,but its not rendering this 
       block and i've tried everything but to no avail..
```

**and on my routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('pages/users', { 
    'pgtopic':'UsersInfo Page',
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My problem is I can't get the contents of this block `xcontent` to render on the `main.jade` layout.

Comment: If you are doing `res.render('layouts/main'` wouldn't Jade just look at that and only render the `main.jade`?  Have you tried replacing it with `res.render('pages/index'` instead?

Comment: that wont work either, there are actually other pages also utilizing the same layout... thats why

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you mean.  If you want to render `users.jade` you have to tell the response to render it.  Simply saying `res.render('layouts/main'` will not put anything in your `block xcontent` because it's a placeholder.  You have to call out the child component, `users.jade` in this case, and that's how your `block xcontent` is filled out.  Saying `res.render('layouts/main'` only renders the `main.jade` which doesn't know to take `users.jade` and insert it.

Comment: i see what you mean, i was meant to type router.get('/users' and res.render('pages/users', thats was my mistake, let me correct it, and yet it still doesnt work appropriately

Comment: Are you seeing any errors, either in the browser or on the server?

Comment: sorry should have gotten back to you, after i made the amendments based on your observation, it worked.. tanks... @MichaelPlatt